# trying to install gcc and g++ on ubuntu 22.04.2 is failing due to 404 not found

Tags: gcc, g++

trying to install gcc and g++ on ubuntu 22.04.2 is failing due to 404 not found from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.15.0-25.25_amd64.deb

Please help

Comment: Verify that your internet is working. Try pinging a website, like Google, by running the command `ping www.google.com`

Comment: `sudo apt install build-essential` ++ ? -> https://itsfoss.com/build-essential-ubuntu/ - And one more thing; you may run into severe problems if you try to replace the installed libc b.t.w. - stay put, don't rock the boat w.r.t. that.